# Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages MYSQL

Tags: linux, ubuntu, mysql

I try to install: `sudo apt install mysql-server`

But have like error like this:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What can I do to solve this error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pixelbook installing r-base dependency with held broken packages error](https://superuser.com/questions/1422059/pixelbook-installing-r-base-dependency-with-held-broken-packages-error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install aptitude:

```
sudo apt-get install aptitude
```

Then execute the below command.

```
sudo aptitude install mysql-server
```

Comment: Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     libdbd-mysql-perl [Not Installed]
2)     libdbi-perl [Not Installed]
3)     libnih-dbus1 [Not Installed]
4)     libterm-readkey-perl [Not Installed]
5)     mountall [Not Installed]
6)     mysql-client-5.5 [Not Installed]
7)     mysql-server [Not Installed]
8)     mysql-server-5.5 [Not Installed]
9)     upstart [Not Installed]



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?]

this is what happen, what can i do?

Comment: @Ade - Do not add follow up questions in the comments. Either Ask a new question or edit and update your original question. As you have accepted this answer as a solution, did this answer therefore solve your original issue and hence your follow up question? If so then aska new question and delete you comment above...